# Smooth animations using GTK+

Tags: animation, gtk, pygtk

I'm creating a network animator (similar to nam, if you have used it before).

Basically, I have nodes represented as small dots on a GTK+ DrawingArea, and I update the positions of these nodes and redraw the DrawingArea in a loop.

The resulting animation is fast, but not smooth (there's a lot of flicker). This is probably because I fill the DrawingArea with a solid color before each frame.

How do you think I can best tackle this problem? Should I pre-render the frames onto Pixbufs? Is there a better solution?

Here's my current drawing code (using PyGTK):

```
rect  = self.drawing_area.get_allocation()
style = self.drawing_area.get_style()

pos   = [n.position_at(self.t) for n in self.nodes]

self.drawing_area.window.draw_rectangle(style.bg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL], True,
                                        0, 0, rect.width, rect.height)

for p in pos:
    self.drawing_area.window.draw_arc(style.fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL], True,
                                      rect.width  * (p.x / 2400.0) - NODE_SIZE/2,
                                      rect.height * (p.y / 2400.0) - NODE_SIZE/2,
                                      NODE_SIZE, NODE_SIZE,
                                      0, 64 * 360)
```

where `self.t` is the current time, which is incremented in the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed my code to render the frames onto a Pixmap, and replaced the DrawingArea with an Image.

While this solved the flickering, now the CPU usage has peaked. The animation is still quite fast, but I don't think this method is scalable.

Time for some optimization, I guess.

**UPDATE:** It turns out using expose-event with an Image wasn't such a good idea. CPU usage is back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

About the expose-event handling, check out the first paragraph on Animations with Cairo + Gtk:P

> **Multi-threaded Animation with Cairo and GTK+**
>   Complex animations with
>   cairo and GTK+ can result in a laggy interface. This is because the
>   gtk_main() thread runs in a single loop. So, if your do_draw()
>   function implements a complicated drawing command, and it is called
>   from the gtk_main() thread (say by an on_window_expose_event()
>   function), the rest of your gtk code will be blocked until the
>   do_draw() function finishes. Consequentially, menu items, mouse
>   clicks, and even close button events will be slow to be processed and
>   your interface will feel laggy.
>
> One solution is to hand off all the processor-intensive drawing to a
>   separate thread, thus freeing the gtk_main() thread to respond to
>   events.

http://cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/